# How to blend two images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I have two images in my view and i need to blend those two images. But the problem is unable to get perfect blend.

Code for the image blend

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(_backGroundImage.frame.size.width, _backGroundImage.frame.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
[_backGroundImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(_backGroundImage.frame.origin.x,_backGroundImage.frame.origin.y,_backGroundImage.frame.size.width,_backGroundImage.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
[_foreGroundImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(_foreGroundImage.frame.origin.x,_foreGroundImage.frame.origin.y,_foreGroundImage.frame.size.width,_foreGroundImage.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeColor alpha:0.5];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[_resultImage setImage:newImage ];
```

I also tried with different blend mode but unable to get result.

[image]
[image]

Please help me to solve this

Comment: Can you give separate image urls for both? I'd like to try myself

Comment: @AkshanshThakur this both are just demo images you can also use different images

Comment: you have to take other image whos backgroud is same as demo image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Change This Line

```
[_foreGroundImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(_foreGroundImage.frame.origin.x,_foreGroundImage.frame.origin.y,_foreGroundImage.frame.size.width,_foreGroundImage.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeLighten alpha:0.5];
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect as i need. Thank you.

Comment: do you know any image magic wand tool which cut some selected part of image? where area of image cut drawn by user.

Comment: unable to find out problem i got.. clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)