# Image Blending using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How can I achieve the output in iOS using Objective-C .. **Image-1 + Image-2 = Image-3 ?**

[image: Image-1]

[image: Image-2]

[image: Image -3]

How can I achieve the output in iOS using Objective-C .. **Image-1 + Image-2 = Image-3** ?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495730/how-to-blend-two-images

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273271/merge-two-image-on-to-one-image-programmatically-in-iphone?rq=1 check this , but it combined 2 images vertically , You can update rect. That might help you !

Comment: Well it seems some one gave down vote to the question. Can you please explain the reason to give the down vote? Im really interested to know that.

Answer (score 5):

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import CoreImage

func aspectFill(from: CGRect, to: CGRect) -> CGAffineTransform {
    let horizontalRatio = to.width / from .width
    let verticalRatio = to.height / from.height
    let scale = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)
    let translationX = horizontalRatio < verticalRatio ? (to.width - from.width * scale) * 0.5 : 0
    let translationY = horizontalRatio > verticalRatio ? (to.height - from.height * scale) * 0.5 : 0
    return CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale).translatedBy(x: translationX, y: translationY)
}

func filter(image: UIImage, texture: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    guard let imageCI = CIImage(image: image),
        let textureCI = CIImage(image: texture)
        else {
            return nil
    }

    let scaleFillTextureCI = textureCI.applying(aspectFill(from: textureCI.extent, to: imageCI.extent))
    let crop = CIFilter(name: "CICrop")!
    crop.setValue(scaleFillTextureCI, forKey: "inputImage")
    crop.setValue(imageCI.extent, forKey: "inputRectangle")

    let alpha = CIFilter(name: "CIConstantColorGenerator")!
    alpha.setValue(CIColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.7), forKey: "inputColor")

    let mix = CIFilter(name: "CIBlendWithAlphaMask")!
    mix.setValue(imageCI, forKey: "inputImage")
    mix.setValue(crop.outputImage, forKey: "inputBackgroundImage")
    mix.setValue(alpha.outputImage, forKey: "inputMaskImage")

    let blend = CIFilter(name: "CIBlendWithMask")!
    blend.setValue(imageCI, forKey: "inputImage")
    blend.setValue(mix.outputImage, forKey: "inputBackgroundImage")
    blend.setValue(imageCI, forKey: "inputMaskImage")

    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    guard let ciImage = blend.outputImage,
        let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else {
            return nil
    }

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
}

let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image.jpg")
let texture = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "texture.jpg")
let output = filter(image: image, texture: texture)]
```

I have solution in `Swift` since I am not familiar with `Objective-C` syntax, but I think you can translate to `Objective-C` easily.
You can achieve the effect by using `CoreImage`. Here the result from Xcode Playground. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZJTC.jpg)